# How to Fix an Incorrect Jinja Substitution

Tags: jinja2, substitution

Sometimes when using jinja substitution into a preset, the characters are not properly encoded and are left as UTF-8 values, for example:

My dynamic preset data contains this field:

"src": ""

and using jinja, I pass it into my preset like this:

"audioTracks": {{DYNAMIC_PRESET_DATA['audioTracks'] | tojson}}

but when I looked at my rendered preset, I get this:

"src": "\u003cchannel-1\u003e"

It appears that the '<' and '>' are not encoded correctly.

Answer (score -1):

To address this issue, you need to use the jinja filter 'replace.'  This will override the encoding step and put what you want to the rendered preset.

In the above example use this jinja substitution in the preset:

```
{{DYNAMIC_PRESET_DATA['audioTracks'] | tojson | replace("\\u003c","<") | replace("\\u003e",">")}}
```